# Splitting field and degree of extension of $x^4 + 2x^2 -2$ over $\mathbb F_{13}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Splitting field and degree of extension of  $x^4 + 2x^2 -2$ over $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb F_{13}$

I already solved it over $\mathbb Q$, but I don't know how it's done over finite fields. I tried looking up some examples but didn't really get what they are doing Could you show me how?. Is it a good idea to do $y=x^2$?

As for the degree of the extension all I know is that it must divide 4!, because there's a theorem: the degree of the extension of the splitting field of a polynomial of degree n divides n!

Comment: $x=4$ is a root. Divide  first $x^4+2x^2-2$ by $x-4$ over $\Bbb F_{13}.$

Comment: @BobDobbs did you determined that just by trial and error?

Comment: yes @darkside https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4%2B2x%5E2-2+mod+13+for+x%3D1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8

Comment: @BobDobbs that's pretty useful. What should I do next since there is no other root?

Comment: When a cubic has no root, it's irreducible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The polynomial is a biquadratic... it is impossible to have a degree 3 splitting field over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: $(x+4)(x+9)(x^2+5)$. But I don't know the construction of the splitting field. I hope somebody explains as an answer.

Comment: @BobDobbs According to the wolfram result. X=-9=4 should not be a root, so?

Comment: @user10354138 Huh? $\mathbb{F}_{p^3}$ is by definition the splitting field of $X^{p^3}-X$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Do they split any biquadratic $aX^4+bX^2+c$?

Comment: @user10354138 I misunderstood your comment, sorry.

Comment: If the biquadratic factors as linear times cubic then the splitting field has degree three or six. Have we established for certain how the biquadratic factors?.

Comment: @darkside https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E4%2B2x%5E2-2+mod+13+for+x%3D9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it for $x^2 + 1$ and $x^2+5$ for better understanding.

As the comments suggested, $f=(x-4)(x+4)(x^2+5)$. So to get the splitting field, you only have to add the roots of $x^2+5=0$ which would be a degree 2 extension.

Comment: Shouldn't I add just one of the roots? The other one is obtained from that isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: $(\frac{-1}{13})=1$ ($-1=5^2$) so you can't use $x^2+1$.

Comment: Yeah, for $x^2+a$ one of the two situations can occur. Splitting field will be either $\mathbb{F}_{13}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{169}$

Comment: Why do we square the 13 in your last comment, is it some theorem?

Comment: Any finite field of characteristic $p$ (prime) will have cardinality $p^a$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$. When your degree 2 polynomial is irreducible the splitting field has degree 2 over $\mathbb{F}_{13}$. So, the cardinality will be $13^2$. There's a theorem that all finite field of same cardinality is isomorphic.

Comment: How do you denote the extension in the exercise $\mathbb F_{13} [\sqrt 5]$? So the elements of this field are of the form $a+b\sqrt 5$ with a and b in $\mathbb F_{13} $, so there are 13x13=169 combinations, I think that's how one gets the cardinality, correct?

Comment: And because of the isomorphism we prefer $\mathbb F_{169} $?

Comment: @darkside Elements are in the form $[ax+b]$ which is called the class of $ax+b$ in the quotient ring $\Bbb F_{13}[x]/(x^2+5)$.

Comment: If it were $\mathbb Q$, and extension is denoted as $Q[\sqrt 5i] $... So why can't I do the same here?